# Laravel & Localization Country + Currency + Language + Timezone

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, localization

We have currently our Project just in Switzerland, like

Example: yourfirm.com
 - Main Language; German
 - Second Languages: English & Turkish
 - Currency: Swiss francs

When User gets to the Page by default he gets the Language German, Swiss francs

We would like to add it as follow:
New Countries: 
Turkey, Main Language: Turkish, Currency: Turkish Lira
Germany & Austria, Main Language: German, Currency: Euro
Rest of Europe: Main Language: English, Currency: Euro
Rest of World: Main Language: English, Currency: USD

So we was thinking to make for each country something like:
When user access yourfirm.com we could determine over his IP the right location (Country, Timezone, Language, Currency) and we could show the right page for his country.
We also have considered to manage it like: for each country from yourfirm.com it would go for example for Germany (DE) -> yourfirm.com/de
Language: German, Currency: €

But we don't know how to solve it exactly: We made some research but couldn't find the right solution. 
Would be great if someone could help us and maybe also try to give us as well an example code.

Comment: This article shows a similar thing to what you're trying to accomplish here, https://codezen.io/implementing-auto-localization-in-laravel-based-on-users-location/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a middleware to detect the geographical location of visitors IP address, one package suggested to integrate is [GeoIP for Laravel 5](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-geoip) ([Documentation](http://lyften.com/projects/laravel-geoip/doc/basic-usage.html)).

**app/Http/Middleware/DetectGeoLocation.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    // check if already detect current session country
    if (!session('country')) {
        $location = geoip();
        session([
            'country' => $location->country,
            'currency' => $location->currency
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then install the middleware to http kernel:

**app/Http/Kernel.php**

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\DetectGeoLocation,
        ...
    ]
```

And now you can get the current session country and currency anywhere:

```
$country = session('country');
$currency = session('currency');
```

Comment: For modern installs use: ```$location->getLocation()->getAttribute('country')``` and ```$location->getLocation()->getAttribute('currency')```